# Autocomplete for #include files

Tags: c++, neovim, language-server-protocol, clangd, nvim-lspconfig

Where do I set the path to include files?
I'm using neovim with nvchad. The project compiles without any issues as the makefile has all the necessary stuff.
How do I get autocomplete within the editor
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8k28.png)

i tried with compile_commands.json but that didn't seem to work

Comment: Please attach [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs), and indicate how you generated the `compile_commands.json` file and where it's located.